# What do these operations mean? $A ∩ B$ or $ A ∪ B$ or $A^c$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random

To be more specific; What does it mean when I read my book:

$A ∩ B = (2, 4) $ ? What does this say about A and B? How are they related?

Same with:
$A ∪ B $

and,

$A^c$ , where c is a complement operator??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \cap B$ is the *intersection* of $A$ and $B$.  It's the set of all elements that are in **both** $A$ **and** $B$.

For example, if $A = [0, 4)$ and $B = (2,5]$, then $A \cap B = (2,4)$.

$A \cup B$ is the *union* of $A$ and $B$.  It's the set of all elements that are in $A$, or in $B$, or in both.

For example, if $A = [0, 4)$ and $B = (2,5]$, then $A \cup B = [0,5]$.

$A^c$ is the *complement* of $A$.  To make sense of complement you need to know what your universal set is.  $A^c$ is the set of everything in the universal set that is **not** in $A$.

For example, if the universal set is $[0,10]$, and $A = [0,3]$, then $A^c = (3,10]$.